# Unmarshalling XML having name value pair in java

Tags: java, xml-parsing

```
<GetDeadlineOffset>
<deadlineCode>DeadlineCode</deadlineCode>
<parameters>
    <parameter name="Name1" value="Value1"/>
    <parameter name="Name2" value="Value2"/>
</parameters>
</GetDeadlineOffset>
```

How to unmarshall this format of xml where we don't have the specified XSD.

Comment: First of all, your xml is not properly structured as there is no closing tag for GetDeadlineOffset. Second, what have you tried? Are you using Xstream, JAXB, etc.?

Comment: sorry for the Structure, I have tried Jaxb but i don't have XSD for this, Can YOu please tell How can i use Xstream for such structure.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what the XML looks like then you can generate an XSD but that isn't required to use XSteam.

XStream has pretty decent documentation on their site so you will want to start off by reading that. The quick overview can be found here: http://x-stream.github.io/tutorial.html

You are going to want to create beans for GetDeadlineOffset and Parameter and then you should be able to use `fromXml()`.

I tend to like using annotations so once you have your annotated beans, you should be able to do something like this:

```
XStream xstream = new XStream();
xStream.processAnnotations(GetDeadlineOffset.class);
xStream.processAnnotations(Parameter.class);
GetDeadlineOffset getDeadlineOffset = (GetDeadlineOffset)xstream.fromXML(xml);
```